# Is there a way to write the same try-except for multiple lines of code without hardcoding? python

Tags: python, error-handling, try-catch, except, hardcode

I have multiple functions that might return `None`:

`do_something()`, `do_something2()`, `do_something3()`, etc.

And to overcome the None Type Errors, from another part of the code I have to hardcode the `try-except` as such:

```
try:
  x = do_other_things(do_something())
except someError: # because of None Type return
  x = None

try:
  y = do_other_things(do_something2())
except someError: # because of None Type return
  y = None
```

Is there any way to just apply the same `try-except` to different lines of code/different function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are testing for the same exception type, then you can wrap the try/except block into a function that accepts as parameters other function and a list of parameters.

```
 def try_except(myFunction, *params):
     try:
         return myFunction(*params)
     except ValueError as e:
         return None
     except TypeError as e:
         return None
```

Comment: For this to work for multiple or no arguments you need to include the star (*) also in the function body: `return myFunction(*params)`

Answer (score 1):

I am not a python expert, but I can think another way.

Create an array of the functions and call them in a loop:

```
listOfFuncs = [do_something,do_something2,do_something3]

results = []*len(listOfFuncs)
for index, func in enumerate(listOfFuncs):
    try:
        results[index] = do_other_things(func())
    except someError:
        results[index] = None
```